# Google Sitemap Generator - set up HTTPS on Linux

Tags: ssl, https, ssh-tunnel, xml-sitemap

i am new to site maps, and Google sitemap generator. 
i am working on a test server and neither localhost nor live. its basically a local test server.
I have installed it and also enabled remote access and am now able to access the admin console using http.
the problem is i need to enable https as well.

when i try to access it through https, i get an "SSL CONNECTION ERROR".

i know that google's documentation on this topic says something like:

---

To set up HTTPS on Linux:

1.Edit the file /usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/conf/httpd.conf.

2.In the VirtualHost section, edit the SSL settings.

3.Save the file.

4.Restart Apache to effect the changes.

---

But in the file httpd.conf, there are no "SSL settings" for me to edit.

Can someone remove this 'vagueness' from the directions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, you have to add to /usr/local/google-sitemap-generator/conf/httpd.conf something like this (into virtualhost directive)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/google-sitemap-generator/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/google-sitemap-generator/server.key
```

This link was helpful for me: http://groups.google.com/group/google-sitemap-generator/browse_thread/thread/a5b0575efad76328

In my case server.crt and server.key files were generated by openssl command (http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html).

Make sure mod_ssl is enabled in Apache (run a2enmod).